# Position absolute with responsive effect

Tags: css, css-position

Beginner in **CSS3**, I wanted to know if there is a **Responsive solution** for "**Position: Absolute**", because when I put in Responsive mode or Mobile device, I see that the element or image **is placed in a single place**, which leave the display a little weird.

Here is an example :

### [image: Example]

"In red": The space added in Responsive mode.

"In blue": The image that is affected by the absolute position.

**Desktop Mode :**

[image: Desktop Mode]

**Code :**

```css
.our-approach-content .delighter-1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 110%;
  top: 0;
}
.our-approach-content .delighter-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90.7%;
  top: 5%;
}
.our-approach-content .delighter-3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 83.05%;
  top: 75%;
}
.our-approach-content .delighter-4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 107%;
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<img class="delighter-1 img-fluid" src="./src/img/delghter-1.png" alt="delighter" width="61" height="61">
          <img class="delighter-2 img-fluid" src="./src/img/delighter-2.png" alt="delighter" width="230" height="230">
          <img class="delighter-3 img-fluid" src="./src/img/delighter-3.png" alt="delighter" width="230" height="230">
          <img class="delighter-4 img-fluid" src="./src/img/delighter-4.png" alt="delighter" width="88" height="88">
```

**Is there another way to position images that are responsive and walk like "Position: Absolute"? Or another solution?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, I can see the undesired behavior but can you please tell us what it should do? Can you post your "responsive" code? What does this element do in desktop mode?

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: I added the desktop mode @A1rPun :)

Comment: I added the code @jjsecord :)

Comment: Use `position: absolute` within a responsive container that is set to `position: relative`.

Comment: @TheScripterX awesome! Can't you just hide the absolute positioned images on mobile? With bootstrap 4 you can do that with `hidden-sm` or `hidden-xs` depending on your needs

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did it ... but it didn't work :/

Comment: @A1rPun Ok ! I'll try it :)

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't really show anything helpful. Where's the lorem ipsum text? Where's the title? You can use a service like http://lorempixel.com/ to include images that everyone can see.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree that the question is not that clear but you don't have to question the content, it could be a prototype.

Comment: @A1rPun I'm not questioning the content. I use lorem ipsum all the time. I'm saying the *code snippet* does not contain the same content as the screen shot.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know that the question is a bit weird but I don't know how to give more details.

I have a div "container" with "col" and I had these small designs that I had to put in the axis of each border.

But I tried the A1rPun (hidden-md) solution and it worked :)!

Thank you very much everyone for your collaboration and help :)